# React-Redux: How do I access the store in Parent Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So I have a React Native application and recently added Redux to it.

Now I am stuck with following problem:

There is a child component (a number slider where you can set the height value of an item) which is called by a parent component. Every time the value of the number slider in the child component changes, I want to have a `console.log` of the updated value in the parent component.

Therefore, the parent component somehow must have access to the Redux store, but I can't figure out how to do this. I tried converting the parent component into a Class Component and call `store.getState();`, but this only gives the initial value of the store and is not updated at all.

So I went back to the parent being a Functional Component and implemented the desired behavior without Redux, but with a callback function. But what do I have Redux for when I'm not using it? In the future I will definitely need Redux in this project and therefore, it would be great to solve this issue using it.

Here is the code without the callback function:

```
Parent.tsx

imports ...
import Child from '../../atoms/Child/Child';
import store from '../../../../index.js';

const Parent: React.FC<Props> = () => {

// console.log('store: ', store.getState()); 

  const renderChild= () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child></Child>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const dataArray = [{content: renderChild()}];

  return (
    <Accordion
      dataArray={dataArray}
    />
  );
};

export default Parent;



Child.tsx

imports ...
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {RootState} from '../../../rootReducer/rootReducer';
import {setHeight} from '../../../store/child/actions';
import {HeightState} from '../../../store/child/types';

type Props = {};

const Child: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(65);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight({height: sliderValue});
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight({height: sliderValue});
  }, [sliderValue]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Height is {sliderValue} inches</Text>
      <Slider
        step={1}
        value={sliderValue}
        onValueChange={sliderValue => setSliderValue(sliderValue)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    height: state.heightResult.height,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setHeight,
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Child);
```

According Redux Devtools, the store is updated correctly and works fine.

Can you please help me?

Comment: You need to wrap `Parent` with `connect` and pass props which you need (use `mapStateToProps` for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the parent to the store also. At the moment your Parent has no idea of the store and has no relationship with it. This is the whole point of redux, flexibility and scalability of the state.

```
const Parent: React.FC<Props> = ({height}) => { 
  console.log('height', height);
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ heightResult: { height }}: RootState) => ({ height });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent);
```